# R: sum columns with two conditions

Tags: r, apply, netcdf, sumifs

I have two data tables. The first table is matrix with coordinates and precipitation. It consists of four columns with latitude, longitude, precipitation and day of monitoring. The example of table is:

`latitude_1     longitude_1 precipitation    day_mon
54.17   62.15   5   34
69.61   48.65   3   62
73.48   90.16   7   96
66.92   90.27   7   19
56.19   96.46   9   25
72.23   74.18   5   81
88.00   95.20   7   97
92.44   44.41   6   18
95.83   52.91   9   88
99.68   96.23   8   6
81.91   48.32   8   96
54.66   52.70   0   62
95.31   91.82   2   84
60.32   96.25   9   71
97.39   47.91   7   76
65.21   44.63   9   3`
 
The second table consists of 5 columns : station number, longitude, latitude, day when monitoring began, day when monitoring ends. It looks like:

`station    latitude_2  longitude_2  day_begin   day_end 
15  50.00   93.22   34  46
11  86.58   85.29   15  47
14  93.17   63.17   31  97
10  88.56   61.28   15  78
13  45.29   77.10   24  79
6   69.73   99.52   13  73
4   45.60   77.36   28  95
13  92.88   62.38   9   51
1   65.10   64.13   7   69
10  60.57   86.77   34  64
3   53.62   60.76   23  96
16  87.82   59.41   38  47
1   47.83   95.89   21  52
11  75.42   46.20   38  87
3   55.71   55.26   2   73
16  71.65   96.15   36  93`

I want to sum precipitations from 1 table. But I have two conditions:

1. **day_begin< day_mon< day_end**. Day of monitoring(day_mon from 1 table) should be less than day of end and more than day of begin (from 2 table)
2. **Sum precipitation from the point which is closer than others**. distance between point of monitoring (coordinates consists
   longitude_1 and latitude_1) and station (coordinates consists
   longitude_2 and latitude_2) should be minimum. The distance is calculated by the formula :
   `R = 6400*arccos(sin(latitude_1)*sin(latitude_2)+cos(latitude_1)*cos(latitude_2))*cos(longitude_1-longitude_2))`

At last I want to get results as table :
`station    latitude_2  longitude_2  day_begin   day_end    Sum
15  50  93.22   34  46  188
11  86.58   85.29   15  47  100
14  93.17   63.17   31  97  116
10  88.56   61.28   15  78  182
13  45.29   77.1    24  79  136
6   69.73   99.52   13  73  126
4   45.6    77.36   28  95  108
13  92.88   62.38   9   51  192
1   65.1    64.13   7   69  125
10  60.57   86.77   34  64  172
3   53.62   60.76   23  96  193
16  87.82   59.41   38  47  183
1   47.83   95.89   21  52  104
11  75.42   46.2    38  87  151
3   55.71   55.26   2   73  111
16  71.65   96.15   36  93  146`

I know how to calculate it in C++. What function should I use in R?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I solved your problem correctly... but here it comes..

I used a data.table approach.

```
library( tidyverse )
library( data.table )


#step 1. join days as periods
#create a dummy variables to create a virtual period in dt1
dt1[, point_id := .I]
dt1[, day_begin := day_mon]
dt1[, day_end := day_mon]
setkey(dt2, day_begin, day_end)
#overlap join finding all stations for each point that overlap periods
dt <- foverlaps( dt1, dt2, type = "within" )

#step 2. calculate the distance station for each point based on TS-privided formula
dt[, distance := 6400 * acos( sin( latitude_1 ) * sin( latitude_2 ) + cos( latitude_1 ) * cos( latitude_2 ) ) * cos( longitude_1 - longitude_2 ) ]

#step 3. filter (absolute) minimal distance based on point_id
dt[ , .SD[which.min( abs( distance ) )], by = point_id ]

#    point_id station latitude_2 longitude_2 day_begin day_end latitude_1 longitude_1 precipitation day_mon i.day_begin i.day_end    distance
# 1:        1       1      47.83       95.89        21      52      54.17       62.15             5      34          34        34  -248.72398
# 2:        2       6      69.73       99.52        13      73      69.61       48.65             3      62          62        62   631.89228
# 3:        3      14      93.17       63.17        31      97      73.48       90.16             7      96          96        96 -1519.84886
# 4:        4      11      86.58       85.29        15      47      66.92       90.27             7      19          19        19  1371.54757
# 5:        5      11      86.58       85.29        15      47      56.19       96.46             9      25          25        25  1139.46849
# 6:        6      14      93.17       63.17        31      97      72.23       74.18             5      81          81        81   192.99264
# 7:        7      14      93.17       63.17        31      97      88.00       95.20             7      97          97        97  5822.81529
# 8:        8       3      55.71       55.26         2      73      92.44       44.41             6      18          18        18  -899.71206
# 9:        9       3      53.62       60.76        23      96      95.83       52.91             9      88          88        88    45.16237
# 10:       10       3      55.71       55.26         2      73      99.68       96.23             8       6           6         6   -78.04484
# 11:       11      14      93.17       63.17        31      97      81.91       48.32             8      96          96        96 -5467.77459
# 12:       12       3      53.62       60.76        23      96      54.66       52.70             0      62          62        62 -1361.57863
# 13:       13      11      75.42       46.20        38      87      95.31       91.82             2      84          84        84  -445.18765
# 14:       14      14      93.17       63.17        31      97      60.32       96.25             9      71          71        71  -854.86321
# 15:       15       3      53.62       60.76        23      96      97.39       47.91             7      76          76        76  1304.41634
# 16:       16       3      55.71       55.26         2      73      65.21       44.63             9       3           3         3 -7015.57516
```

### Sample data

```
dt1 <- read.table( text = "latitude_1     longitude_1 precipitation    day_mon
54.17   62.15   5   34
69.61   48.65   3   62
73.48   90.16   7   96
66.92   90.27   7   19
56.19   96.46   9   25
72.23   74.18   5   81
88.00   95.20   7   97
92.44   44.41   6   18
95.83   52.91   9   88
99.68   96.23   8   6
81.91   48.32   8   96
54.66   52.70   0   62
95.31   91.82   2   84
60.32   96.25   9   71
97.39   47.91   7   76
65.21   44.63   9   3", header = TRUE ) %>% 
  setDT()

dt2 <- read.table( text = "station    latitude_2  longitude_2  day_begin   day_end 
15  50.00   93.22   34  46
                   11  86.58   85.29   15  47
                   14  93.17   63.17   31  97
                   10  88.56   61.28   15  78
                   13  45.29   77.10   24  79
                   6   69.73   99.52   13  73
                   4   45.60   77.36   28  95
                   13  92.88   62.38   9   51
                   1   65.10   64.13   7   69
                   10  60.57   86.77   34  64
                   3   53.62   60.76   23  96
                   16  87.82   59.41   38  47
                   1   47.83   95.89   21  52
                   11  75.42   46.20   38  87
                   3   55.71   55.26   2   73
                   16  71.65   96.15   36  93", header = TRUE ) %>% 
  setDT()
```